# Which programming languages have REPLs that can display graphical data?

Tags: read-eval-print-loop

I'm starting to feel disappointed with REPLs that force me to do everything with text. I've used several environments that allow the presentation and manipulation of graphical data, and I wish all languages had it. Here's a short list of the graphical REPLs (in the broad sense) I'm aware of:

1. CAS typically have this: Mathematica, Maple, Axiom, MuPad, Sage*, etc.
2. The most recent version of IPython (notebook interface)
3. DrRacket
4. Factor's REPL

Are there any for other languages out there?

* If it weren't for IPython I'd recommend Sage notebooks to all python users, even non-mathematical ones.

Comment: There seems to be something like this for Clojure! See http://cemerick.com/2011/10/26/enabling-richer-interactions-in-the-clojure-repl/

Comment: Just to add to your mention of DrRacket, there's also image support in the [Geiser REPL](http://www.nongnu.org/geiser/geiser_3.html#The-REPL) inside Emacs.

Answer (score 1):

Lisp:

- *Dynamic Windows* of the Symbolics Lisp Machine operating system (Genera)
- *Common Lisp Interface Manager* (CLIM), *McCLIM*

Answer (score 0):

Julia has together with the IPython team released a Julia backend for the IPython notebook, called [IJulia](https://github.com/JuliaLang/IJulia.jl). It has gotten a good reputation in the Julia community and since MIT has began to do many of it's numerical analysis courses in Julia they have also released a [nice little document](https://github.com/stevengj/julia-mit/blob/master/README.md) explaining the reasoning behind the decision and a good intro to using Julia with the IPython/IJulia notebook.